# If/else statement in button in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have the following code:

```
<body onload="reset()">

    <div id="menu" class="menu"></div>

    <div id="container">
        <button onclick="openMenu()">Open Menu</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function reset(){

            var flag = true;    
            document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = flag;           

        }

        function openMenu(){

            if (flag = true) {
                var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
                menu.className = 'menu2';
                flag = false;
            }else {
                var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
                menu.className = 'menu';
                flag = true;
            };

            document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = flag;

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

and the css is:

```css
#menu{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #232323;
}

.menu{
 height: 400px;
}

.menu2{
 height: 600px;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

The problem is that the first time I press the button, the div changes its height to 600px like it's supposed to do.
But the second time I press it (and with the "flag" variable being false at this point) the div doesn't go back to the "menu" class changing its height back to 400px.
I can't seem to find why this happens.

Comment: `if (flag = true)` is not a comparison!

Comment: if (flag = true) { <- This should be a double equals, at least.

Comment: Also, are you pulling a variable called `flag` out of thin air? Or is it initialized somewhere else?

Comment: @DrewKennedy my bad, yes "flag" is declared as true when the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (flag = true) {
```

need to be

```
if (flag == true) {
```

or

```
if (flag === true) {
```

or

```
if (flag) {
```

use a tool like jshint or jslint

Comment: That would be a bug too. :)

Comment: Technically, it's not necessary, as the ELSE will catch the "flag undefined" condition, and then inside it sets the flag variable for a subsequent run. (But I agree it's bad form, I usually set 'global' flags like this at the top of my doc somewhere.)

Comment: @Teemu my bad, the variable "flag" is actually defined as true when the page loads, I just didn't add it to my code by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (flag = true) {
```

has to be

```
if (flag == true) {
```

and you should make a variable flag, otherwise you cant check for it to be true, like this:

```
var flag = true; // or false, just what you want for flag to be in the first place
```